# Automatical Recovery of Deleted Element's style

Tags: html, jquery, dom, dom-events

Let's say I have a simple .html like below:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
<span>This is the First Span</span>
<span style="color:red;">This is the Second Span</span>
</div>
```

Step1)
let's say the mouse cursor(caret) is on the last text(...Second Span|)

Step2)
let's say I did press <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> until the second span disappears on the page.

Step3)
*And let's say I entered text, like abc, RIGHT AFTER the 2nd step.

In this case... a font-tag comes-up suddenly on the the newly inserted text 'abc'
and even the new text has `color:red` style! which seems like come from the previously deleted span like below.

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
This is the First Span<font color="#ff0000">abc</font></div>
```

I'd like to know the reason why the new font-tag automatically appears on the page ...to prevent browser from inserting a new tag which I didn't mean to do

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of what the final result looks like? And when you say "typing" are you referring to the actual HTML source, or a browser event when the user enters backspace?

Comment: The Backspace happens on the browser and the font-tag comes up on the source code. I added result code on.

Comment: So you're saying there's javascript code which is running on the client that is bound to the keypress event which is modifying the DOM when the backspace key is held. Is that correct?

Comment: Nope, I only have html file...no javascript file. I could do some work on .js to prevent this action after I become to know why is this happening